# How to pass variables beween steps secretly?

Tags: github, github-actions

GitHub Actions allows you to pass environmental variables from one step to the other by doing

```
echo "::set-env name=YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME::YOUR_VALUE"
```

in one step, and then accessing the value in the next step

```
${{ env.YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME }}
```

However, this prints the variable value to the GitHub Actions runner's console. This is problematic if one step generates some kind of a secret value and wants to pass it to the next step.

Is it possible to pass variables secretly, without them being printed in the log? Note that it looks like the `env` object cannot be accessed by programs directly. Instead, an environmental variable has to explicitly be set in the `env:` section (e.g. `YOUR_ENV_VAR: ${{ env.YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME }}`, which always prints the value to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mask a value so that it will appear in the log as `***`. See the [documentation here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#masking-a-value-in-log).

```
echo "::add-mask::Mona The Octocat"
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd just like to add that this above is a standalone command (in its own line), and all usages of the string that are later printed to the console will be masked. I think also that this only applies in subsequent steps.